# User 'message' in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

In Exchange 2010, its possible to set a user message that appears in Outlook 2010 above the 'Send' button when composing a new email.  Can anyone advise where this is configured?

Thanks, Duncan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to MailTips. I have not played with Exchange 2010 yet, but I did find [this article](http://www.winadmins.net/2010/03/07/customizing-exchange-2010-mailtips/). I hope that helps.

Comment: A search on this got me to the MS KB article.. many thanks!